# Chinese show where a boy befriends a robot who was able to disguise itself as a toy

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember the beginning: the main character waking up in his bed.
The show's premise was around a male teen (I think) who lived under a family convenience store/diary that had toy machines.

What made the show stand out to me a lot was how he befriended this miniature animated/robot and definitely was involved in a “saving the world type of way”.

I remember that the robot was able to go still and disguise as a toy whenever strangers (like the mom for example) by staying still. I also vaguely remember a part where there turned out to be another one (which could fly, due to it flying through the city at one point) who the main characters robot had chased down.

I remember watching the ending when I didn’t even finish the whole series and the part I remember the best. The ending was located in a traditional/ancient Chinese temple with the stairs and everything and the robot told the teen to run away but he refused.

The ending was the same as the beginning due to him waking up in his bed.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi SE! Was this a 3D animated show, live action or a 2D cartoon? Why was the robot telling the teen to run away? Was the teen in danger?